# Access C constants (header) from JNI (Java Native Interface)

Tags: java, c, header, java-native-interface, constants

how do I access constants defined in the C header file from Java side (through JNI)?

I have a C library with this header file c_header.h:

```
// I'll try to get these values in java
#define PBYTES 64
#define SBYTES 128
#define SGBYTES 128
```

Then I have this java code libbind_jni.java:

```
package libbind;

public class libbind_jni {
static{
    try {
        System.load("libbind_jni.so");
    } catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
        System.err.println("Native code library failed to load.\n" + e);
        System.exit(1);
    }
}

public static native String[] pubm(String seed);
```

Then running javah at libbind_jni.java I generate JNI header file jni_header.h:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     libbind_libbind_jni
 * Method:    pubm
 * Signature: (Ljava/lang/String;)[Ljava/lang/String;
 */
JNIEXPORT jobjectArray JNICALL Java_lib_f_1jni_pubm
  (JNIEnv *, jclass, jstring);
```

Then I write  a little C code for JNI library jni_source.c:

```
#include "jni_header.h"
#include "c_header.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

JNIEXPORT jobjectArray JNICALL Java_libbind_libbind_1jni_pubm
  (JNIEnv *env, jclass cls, jstring jniSeed){
    unsigned char vk[PBYTES];
    unsigned char sk[SBYTES];
    <whatever...>
}
```

-- Here goes compiling of C library for java -- libbind.so

And the JAVA source j_source.java:

```
import libbind.libbind_jni;

public class test {

    /* trying to access constants from library (libbind.so) */
    System.out.println(libbind_jni.PBYTES);
    System.out.println(libbind_jni.SBYTES);
    System.out.println(libbind_jni.SGBYTES);

}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    test();
}


$ javac test.java

test.java:5: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable PBYTES
location: class libbind.libbind_jni
    System.out.println(libbind_jni.PBYTES);
```

So the question is: How do I access these definitions/constants in C header file from Java?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple answer is that you can't. You'll have to define the same values in Java.

```
public static final int PBYTES = 64;
public static final int SBYTES = 128;
public static final int SGBYTES = 128;
```

Or you can define some native methods that return these values. But the macros as such cannot be accessed from Java.

```
public static native int PBYTES();
public static native int SBYTES();
public static native int SGBYTES();
```

Comment: What about the other way around -- accessing Java constants from C++? Is there a way to avoid defining the same values in the C++ code?

Comment: @biggvsdiccvs Yes that can be done since Java constants are just normal class members. You need to do some heavy JNI coding though.

Comment: I haven't actually done any JNI coding yet (but quite a lot of pure Java coding). If you could point me in the right direction, I would really appreciate it. I'm trying to write Java wrappers for a couple of camera drivers. The C++ APIs have a bunch of setter methods for different parameters (e.g. exposure and shutter mode etc etc) and I thought that having a single setter with a key-value pair might be less work, but the keys and some values should be defined as constants. Would that actually be less work?

Comment: It's worth pointing out that they cannot actually be accessed by the C++ code either because they no longer exist (at runtime). Macros are just a way of writing reusable code, they're inlined during the "preprocessing" phase of compilation. If the macros are dynamic (such as version info etc) then you could set the java constant in the JNI_OnLoad method.